# Criar Biblioteca Javascript

Tags: javascript, biblioteca

gostaria de saber como posso criar minha própria biblioteca javascript, ou seja, criar funções que poderão ser reaproveitadas em vários projetos e com personalização fácil.

Sei que já existem diversas bibliotecas por aí muito boas(JQuery por exemplo), mas esta pergunta é somente para meu aprendizado e crescimento como profissional, acredito que será de grande ajuda para outros também.

Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Acho que um bom começo seria estudando o padrão `Module`.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var Counter = (function(){
  var count = 0;

  return {
      count: function() {
        return count;
      }

    , increment: function() {
        return count += 1;
      }
  };
})()

Counter.increment(); // Imprime: 1
Counter.increment(); // Imprime: 2
Counter.increment(); // Imprime: 3
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou agora mesmo estudar.

Comment: Só me diz uma coisa, no caso de eu querer fazer uma função cujas váriaveis do método a ser executado tenham um valor padrão, mas que possam ser alterados caso queira fazê-lo, eu faria isso com parâmetros na função imediata mesmo? Um exemplo do que estou falando é o fadeIn() do JQuery, que tem um valor padrão para duração, mas que pode ser personalizado.

Comment: @Lucas, creio que isso seja uma outra pergunta. Mas o jQuery trata isso internamente, dentro da função

Comment: Não marque a resposta como resolvido ainda. Creio que respostas melhores irão surgir

Comment: Ok, vou aguardar

Answer (score 5):

Qualquer pessoa pode criar uma biblioteca, e isso é muito útil em projetos pequenos onde se precisa de métodos específicos e tantas vezes que fica melhor organizar o código.

Basicamente há duas abordagens. Criar funções que aceitem todos os dados como argumentos, ou extendendo o protótipo de elementos do DOM ou dos *tipos* de JavaScript.

O jQuery abordou pela primeira opção, o MooTools por exemplo pela segunda.

Em qualquer dos casos é importante ter em conta que pode haver choques com outras bibliotecas e por isso planear bem que nomes se usam.

Se quiseres uma API à volta de um objeto, teu, poderias fazer assim:

```
var MetodosMeus = {
    foo: function(str){
        // fazer algo
    },
    bar: function(arr){
        // fazer algo
    }
};
```

E depois chamas por exemplo:

```
var strLimpa = MetodosMeus.limpar(stringSuja);
```

Fazendo o mesmo via extensão no protótipo seria

```
String.prototype.limpar = function(){
    // fazer algo
};
```

e para usar seria:

```
var strLimpa = stringSuja.limpar();
```

Referi em cima o MooTools que é também uma biblioteca modular, que o jQuery não permite da mesma maneira. Assim se a tua biblioteca ficar grande o melhor é ter módulos que possam funcionar como acrescentos. Desse modo podes usar só o que precisas e manter o código e ficheiros leves.